# Why column count is 0 for GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Friends, I'm populating a GridView in my asp.net application using following code.

```
    GridView grdExport = new GridView();
    DataSet dsRecord = objHelper.gReturnDataSet(CommandType.Text, strSql);

    grdExport.DataSource = dsRecord.Tables[0];
    grdExport.DataBind();
```

Now the problem is in immediate window, when I'm checking, I'm getting following result:

```
    ?dsRecord.Tables[0].Columns.Count
    16
    ?dsRecord.Tables[0].Rows.Count
    37
    ?grdExport.Rows.Count
    37
    ?grdExport.Columns.Count
    0
```

Please, can anyone tell me why Column count is 0 for grdExport?

Comment: *Automatically generated bound column fields are not added to the Columns collection.* [Hence the count would be zero](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx)

Comment: If you want the count it would be same as the source table you are assigning , **16**

Comment: @V4Vendetta thanks a lot. I didn't know it..

Comment: set autogeneatedcolumns=true for the gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GridView.Columns Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns.aspx)

Check this:

> The Columns property (collection) is used to store all the explicitly
>   declared column fields that get rendered in the GridView control. You
>   can also use the Columns collection to programmatically manage the
>   collection of column fields.

*If you have more columns to your added columns in your grid then it will show count of those columns which you have added not the auto generated columns.*

If you show auto generated columns then it will show 0. 
Check this markup:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Now it will Show your result of columns's count to 1:
//Before adding column to gridview

```
?dtResult.Rows.Count
9
?dtResult.Columns.Count
2
?GridView1.Rows.Count
9
?GridView1.Columns.Count
0
```

After Adding column to gridview.

```
?GridView1.Columns.Count
1
```

Answer (score 1):

It shows the `counts = 0` because by default autogenerated columns is true If you add manual colums then it will shows the column counts. 
If you write `grdExport.AutoGenerateColumns = false`; then no columns would rendered in page.

Answer (score 1):

May be it is because you didnt place gridView on page?
like this:PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(grdExport)

Answer (score 0):

Instead ?grdExport.Columns.Count. This count you get when you add columns collection in gridview at design time.
You have to use 
grdExport.Rows[0].Cells.Count

Comment: your solution helps to get the data in the row, not header. Thanks anyway.

Comment: For header "HeaderRow.Cells.Count" is there.

Answer (score 0):

Your GridViewColumn Column will be set after binding your data. So just show a `MessageBox.Show` to find the column count.

```
grdExport.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
MessageBox.Show(grdExport.Columns.Count.ToString());
```