# Access the data in Gridview in runtime when it set auto generate?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i imported my data from Excel sheet to grid view.after that i want to put the column header text of my grid view into drop down,but i can't access them
help me plz :-( ;

this is my code but it dose not work :

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
* for (int i = 0; i < dg_excel.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    lst.Add(dg_excel.Columns[i].HeaderText);
}
ddl_prd_count.DataSource;
ddl_prd_count.DataBind();
```

for this `*` line it says to me there are no columns (column.count = 0)

Comment: Why don't you perform loop on your data source instead of grid ??

Comment: dg_excel's columns are auto generated, if so then iterate column name from its datasource, else you know the column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9817850/770710) on another SO thread [Why column count is 0 for GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817597/why-column-count-is-0-for-gridview) to know that why are you not able to access the columns from your grid's Columns collection.

In my opinion, if you want to use auto generated columns then follow this ASP.net forum link - [Customizing Auto Generated Columns (GridView)](http://forums.asp.net/t/888287.aspx) and SO thread [How to hide columns in an ASP.NET GridView with auto-generated columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091457/how-to-hide-columns-in-an-asp-net-gridview-with-auto-generated-columns).

e.g.
have an idea from this code.. i have not checked the proper syntax etc in it.

```
 protected void MyGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        if (IsFillCombo)
        {
            //fill your list here.
            for (int i = 0; i < datasourcetable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                lst.Add(e.Row.Cells[i].Text);
            }
            IsFillCombo = false;
        }
    }
}
```

// Another simplest way to implement this as below: From [Question Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817597/why-column-count-is-0-for-gridview)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                List<Abc> listofAbc = new List<Abc>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    listofAbc.Add(new Abc
                    {
                        ID = i + 1,
                        Name = "Abc" + (i + 1).ToString()
                    });
                }
                GridView1.DataSource = listofAbc;
                GridView1.DataBind();

                List<string> lst = new List<string>();

                for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
                {

                    lst.Add(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class Abc
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use following code

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < dg_excel.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
{

    lst.Add(dg_excel.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text);

}

ddl_prd_count.DataSource=lst ;

ddl_prd_count.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Access `gridView1_CellValueChanged` event of your grid
and then access`e.Column.FieldName.ToString()`