# ASP.NET Gridview Binding to LINQ Dataset ColumnCount

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, gridview, ado.net

I am trying to bind a asp.net gridview to a linq query result. It works but I am unable to get a count of columns in the resultset. Following is the code in the pageLoad event.

```
Dim resultSet = (From item In db.wthistory Select item).ToList
GridView1.DataSource =resultSet 
GridView1.DataBind()
Response.Write(GridView1.Rows.Count) ' this works and prints the correct number of rows
Response.Write(GridView1.Columns.Count) 'this always prints 0 !
```

The Gridview does bind correctly and shows the correct data but why is the columncount 0?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the column count being zero is probably unrelated to the use of LINQ. The behavior is instead due to the AutoGenerateColumns property being set to true on the GridView. See this thread for details:

[Why column count is 0 for GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817597/why-column-count-is-0-for-gridview)